# The app gets crashed because of xcglogger swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcglogger

I am using the XCGLogger with correct compatibility (My Swift language is 3.2 and XCGLogger version is 5.0.5)

But still the app crashes with the following crash report

```
8 XCGLogger 0x105994420 _T0s11_StringCoreV6appendyABFTfq4gXn_n + 280
9 XCGLogger 0x105994290 _T0S2SSaySSG19stringInterpolationd_tcfCTfq4nd_n     + 136
10 XCGLogger 0x1059a2784 _.  T09XCGLogger15BaseDestinationC7processyAA10LogDetailsV03logF0_tFTf4gn_n + 3168
11 XCGLogger 0x1059a0894 _T09XCGLogger15BaseDestinationCAA0C8ProtocolA2aDP7processyAA10LogDetailsV03logG0_tFTW + 596
12 XCGLogger 0x1059c0888 _T09XCGLoggerAAC5loglnyAB5LevelO_SS12functionNameSS04fileE0Si10lineNumbers10DictionaryVySSypG8userInfoypSgyc7closuretFTf4ngXgXnggn_n + 636
13 XCGLogger 0x1059bbbac _T09XCGLoggerAAC7verboseyypSgyXK_s12StaticStringV12functionNameAF04fileF0Si.   10lineNumbers10DictionaryVySSypG8userInfotFTm + 500
14 XCGLogger 0x1059baaa8 _T09XCGLoggerAAC5debugyypSgyXK_s12StaticStringV12functionNameAF04fileF0Si10lineNumbers10DictionaryVySSypG8userInfotF + 32
15 Quickride 0x104281c58 QRSessionManager.onResumeUserSession() throws -> () (QRSessionManager.swift:154)
16 Quickride 0x104544de4 specialized SessionManagerController.(resumeUserSession(sessionChangeCompletionListener : SessionChangeCompletionListener?) -> ()).(closure #2) (SessionManagerController.swift:84)
17 Quickride 0x104543cdc partial apply for SessionManagerController.(resumeUserSession(sessionChangeCompletionListener : SessionChangeCompletionListener?) -> ()).(closure #2) (SessionManagerController.swift)
18 Quickride 0x104133230 thunk (RideManagementModuleSessonHandler.swift)
19 libdispatch.dylib 0x1845c4a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20 libdispatch.dylib 0x184601ff4 _dispatch_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
21 Quickride 0x104541cc4 SessionManagerController.resumeUserSession(sessionChangeCompletionListener : SessionChangeCompletionListener?) -> () (SessionManagerController.swift:94)
22 Quickride 0x1044bd334 AppStartupHandler.(resumeUserSessionAndNavigateToAppropriateInitialView() -> ()).(closure #1) (AppStartupHandler.swift:33)
23 Quickride 0x104133230 thunk (RideManagementModuleSessonHandler.swift)
24 libdispatch.dylib 0x1845c4aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
25 libdispatch.dylib 0x1845c4a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
26 libdispatch.dylib 0x1846064e0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 876
27 libdispatch.dylib 0x184606110 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1848f7fac _pthread_wqthread + 1176
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1848f7b08 start_wqthread + 4
```

Here is the code where the crash occurs:

```
public func onResumeUserSession() throws {
    AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().log.debug("onResumeUserSession()")
    try validateUserSessionBeforeResuming()
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information or code to really dig into the issue.

However, you're using a version of XCGLogger that's over a year old, as well as an old version of Swift. Are you still using an old Xcode version as well?

I would recommend updating to Xcode 10 (the most current version at the time I'm writing this), update all libraries (including XCGLogger) to the most recent versions, and update your project to Swift 4.2.

There have been lots of fixes over the last year and I'm sure you'll find this crash goes away once you've updated.